# Rewrite a URL via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL in the following structure like

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html
```

I want to rewrite the URL like

```
http://www.naturaflowers.com/fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html
```

We used "ultimate SEO url Plugin" to generate SEO friendly URL. The old URL structure is /index.php?main_page=index&cPath=category_id . My htaccess code is as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

> The above mentioned plugin and this htaccess code rewrite
>   index.php?main_page=index&cPath=100 to
>   /100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html . And now I want to
>   /100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html rewrite to
>   /fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html everywhere in my website through
>   htaccess .

Comment: "Please help me" is not a question. And if you've already asked five URL rewriting question, but took away *nothing* from any of the answers, and can't be bothered to familiarize yourself with it, then this is hardly worth answering.

Comment: How are your pages created? When you rewrite a URL, the browser actually loads the new URL instead of the old one. So if your HTML file is actually stored at `100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html` and you rewrite it to `fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html`, it won't load the correct page.

Comment: Why do you want to remove `/100-` from URL and what is your actual filename?

Comment: @anubhava the actual file name is /index.php?main_page=index&cPath=100 . We use a plugin to remove this structure to implement SEO friendly URL. The url structure become /100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html. I want to rewrite /100-fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html to /fresh-cut-wholesale-flowers.html . is it possible Sir?

Comment: Possible but you should update the question with full .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava I update the question , please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[0-9]+-(.+?\.html)$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Really you are master

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(/?)\d+-(.*)$ $1$2
```